# Debugging, bad position

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am trying to make a android game but everytime i load it, the game crashes and this shows up as the log:

```
01-30 05:46:50.557: W/dalvikvm(30824): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e38300)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 636
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad position (limit 0): 2
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at java.nio.Buffer.positionImpl(Buffer.java:364)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:358)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.gl.Vertices.bind(Vertices.java:71)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.gl.SpriteBatcher.endBatch(SpriteBatcher.java:44)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at com.customgame.GameScreen.present(GameScreen.java:223)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.GLGame.onDrawFrame(GLGame.java:97)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
01-30 05:46:50.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30824):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

can someone help me out in what the problem is here? mainly, i dont understand what it means when they say Bad position on the second row. does that mean im not allowed to place a sprite on a particular area?

Comment: If you post code from the relevant areas, it'll be easier for people to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Buffer` objects have a `capacity` (how much data the buffer can hold), a `limit` (how far into the buffer you can access data), and a `position` (the offset at which data will be read or written).  `Vertices.bind()` is attempting to set the position to 2, but the buffer's limit has been set to zero.

See also the [NIO Buffer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred because I was not stopping bluetooth scan. I started bluetooth scan, selected the device and carried on with the app.

All activities launched after `BluetoothScanActivity` crashed and app came to `BluetoothScanActivity`. This occurred sometimes after few seconds and sometimes after few minutes.

It was fixed by calling this in `onStop` of `BluetoothScanActivity`-

```
mScanner.stopScan(mCallback);
```